# Resize MFT Issues: Video Composition in Windows Media Foundation

Tags: winapi, video, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to do composition with two separate video sources in Media Foundation.  I am attempting to encode a video with a video overlay.  To do so I am attempting to use the [Video Resizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819491(v=vs.85).aspx) on the smaller input.

I've seen several threads on this, but I thought I'd ask around in any case.

Basically the idea is to create two source readers and a sink writer.  The source files are h264, so I use the reader to decode into YUY2.  While processing samples, I send the appropriate sample to the Resize MFT, then down the line (I haven't made it this far) I combine the two images to create the overlay effect with MFCopyImage.

**My question is:**  I am getting an E_INVALIDARG when I call ProcessInput on the Resize MFT.
To initialize the mft, I am giving it the appropriate type from the reader via SetInput Type.  After that I am setting all the appropriate properties via the PropertyStore, and then updating the framesize for the output type of the MFT.  I have read the documentation and modeled my implementation according to the [MFT Processing Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965264(v=vs.85).aspx).

None of these steps raise any red flags until I actually attempt to use ProcessInput.

Although I have limited experience in Windows Media Foundation, I have been able to use the Framerate DSP with success.  I would appreciate **any** advice.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else stuck in a similar situation, I ended up not using the Resizer MFT but the [Video Processor MFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162913(v=vs.85).aspx) which worked with much less effort.

Comment: is it also working on windows 7 or higher version only?

Comment: My understanding is that the Video Processor MFT is only 8.1 and higher.